# Knockoutjs , cancel observable update

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have the following JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rayray/KAa6S/ .
When I click Edit folder a dialog pops up and I can edit the name. The folder name of the form then changes due to it being an knockoutjs obsevable.
How can I cancel and revert to the old data once the cancel button is clicked.

Comment: This post might give you some ideas: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

Answer (score 0):

Just save the current value of `folderName` when the edit folder link is clicked.  If the cancel button is clicked, set `folderName` back to that value.